# Libraries Not Copying Correctly

Tags: c#, recursion

I have a recursive set of methods for copying a large fileshare to a new destination and, while copying, keeps track of how many items are in the destination folders it creates to break up the source fileshare into smaller libraries. The bug is two phased:

**First:**

In the process of switching between libraries(example: stop copying to library1 and start copying to library2) It copies unwanted files and folders over to the first library before switching.

**Second:**

It copies the first few files to the second library then stops, and when I break and look at the local variables it's looking as if it's running unmanaged code and thus I can't see the exact value of the different variables when it get's stuck.

**What I'm looking for:**

I'm looking for a way to resolve this bug and stop copying files to the first library when it hits a certain amount of items(files and folders) and start copying to the next library while carrying over the overflow list instance being created in the method.

**Recursive Method Region:**

```
#region Recursive_Copy
    private static List<string> AccessDeniedList = new List<string>();
    public static void RecursiveCopy(string SourceDir, string DestDir, List<string> OverFlow, bool ToSwitch, bool FirstTime)
    {
        OverFlow = OFlowChecker(OverFlow);
        CopyData Data = new CopyData();
        string CurrentLibrary = CopyData.CurrentWorkingLibrary;
        int LibCount = Data.LibraryCount();

        if (FirstTime)
        {
            NewLibrary(SourceDir, OverFlow, ToSwitch, FirstTime);
        }
        else if (ToSwitch || LibCount >= CopyData.CountLimit)
        {
            NewLibrary(SourceDir, OverFlow, ToSwitch, FirstTime);
        }
        else if (!ToSwitch && LibCount <= CopyData.CountLimit)
        {
            LibCount = Data.LibraryCount();
            if (CurrentLibrary == @"N:\atf\Library3" || CurrentLibrary == @"N:\atf\Library7")
            {
                // Break Point
                Debugger.Break();
            }
            try
            {
                CopyData OFlow = new CopyData();
                DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(SourceDir);
                DirectoryInfo[] dirs = dir.GetDirectories();
                FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles();
                if (!Directory.Exists(DestDir))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(DestDir);
                }

                if (files.Count() > 0)
                {
                    EnumFiles(files, DestDir, dir.FullName, ref OverFlow, ref LibCount);
                }

                if (dirs.Count() > 0)
                {
                    EnumFolders(dirs, SourceDir, DestDir, CurrentLibrary, LibCount, OverFlow);
                }
            }
            catch (PathTooLongException)
            {
                // Break Point
                DirectoryInfo DirInst = new DirectoryInfo(SourceDir);
                CopyData.OutOfReachAreas.Add(DirInst.FullName);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                // Break Point
                Console.WriteLine("\nError During Copying:\n" + e.Message + "\nSource:\n" + e.Source);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("There Was A LibraryMisDirectException. This Error Is Common But If It Persists Contact Your Developer.");
            // Break Point
            RecursiveCopy(SourceDir, DestDir, OverFlow, false, false);
        }
    }

    private static void EnumFiles(FileInfo[] files, string DestDir, string CurrentLibrary, ref List<string> OverFlow, ref int RunningCount)
    {
        CopyData data = new CopyData();
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            if (!(RunningCount + 1 >= CopyData.CountLimit))
            {
                try
                {
                    string temppath = Path.Combine(DestDir, file.Name);
                    if (!(new FileInfo(temppath).Exists && AccessDeniedList.Contains(file.Name)))
                    {
                        RunningCount++;
                        file.CopyTo(temppath, true);
                    }
                }
                catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
                {
                    AccessDeniedList.Add(file.Name);
                    Console.WriteLine("\nAccess Was Denied Accessing:\n" + file.Name + "\nIn:\n" + file.Directory.FullName);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                OverFlow.Add(file.FullName);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void EnumFolders(DirectoryInfo[] directories, string Source, string Destination, string CurrentLibrary, int CurrentCount, List<string> OverFlow)
    {
        CopyData data = new CopyData();
        foreach (var subDir in directories)
        {
            CurrentLibrary = CopyData.CurrentWorkingLibrary;
            if ((data.LibraryCount() + 1 + subDir.GetFiles().Count()) >= CopyData.CountLimit)
            {
                // Break Point
                RecursiveCopy(subDir.FullName, Destination, OverFlow, true, false);
            }
            else
            {
                string temppath = Path.Combine(Destination, subDir.Name);
                RecursiveCopy(subDir.FullName, temppath, OverFlow, false, false);
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion
```

**CopyData Class:**

```
#region Public Data
    public static string SourceDirectory { get; set; }

    public static string DestinationContainer { get; set; }

    public static string CurrentWorkingLibrary { get; set; }

    public static int LibraryCounter = 0;

    public static List<string> OutOfReachAreas = new List<string>();

    public List<string> OverFlowFiles = new List<string>();

    public static int CountLimit = 1000;

    public int LibraryCount()
    {
        if (CurrentWorkingLibrary != null)
        {
            try
            {
                DirectoryInfo LibDir = new DirectoryInfo(CurrentWorkingLibrary);
                int files = LibDir.GetFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Count();
                int folders = LibDir.GetDirectories("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Count();
                int sum = files + folders;
                return sum;
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                return 0;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            CurrentWorkingLibrary = DestinationContainer + "\\Library" + LibraryCounter.ToString();
            return 0;
        }
    }
    #endregion
```

**Notes:**

I have tried stepping through this process and you will see marked in the code where I put break points, I have google extensively and been debugging this problem for about two weeks now. So any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: out of curiousity, any threading involved?

Comment: I have to say that I find the heavy use of `static` in CopyData and combined with many `new`s of CopyData's rather confusing.  Maybe try a more object oriented approach, which is to say, remove the static fields from CopyData, and then share CopyData objects only as needed.  If I had to guess I'd say that the instance method LibraryCount is overwriting some of those statics unexpectedly.

Comment: @Icepickle Not at the moment that I know of. I have not studied multithreading very much as of yet unfortunately.

Comment: @ErikEidt Yeah I agree, the static fields I was using as unchanging values for the methods to reference, like the source and destination root entered by the user never change through the process and the current library changed by the library counter method if it varies from the library counter integer to ensure the library being counted is the current library, however that could be my problem if it starts counting the new library before the copying switches over to it. Anyways a more object oriented, like making the libraries more like objects than folders in the view of the methods?

Comment: I ended up just tossing most of my Recursive Copy method and the whole CopyData class and rewriting it using the tips and advice both of you gave me. I integrated multithreading and more object oriented classes and methodology when building my recursive method. After a bit of debugging it seems to be working great. I tested it making smaller libraries and made about 20 successfully. I'm going to test it out making full libraries then if it's working post the new code in an answer. Thank you for the help.